# Determining the type of motherboard in a server

Tags: central-processing-unit, hardware

I was wondering if I could get some advice from the community. I am trying to identify a type of motherboard used in this particular product:

[LINK TO PRODUCT](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16859107052&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Server/Workstation%20Systems-_-N82E16859107052&gclid=CPriupm4mLgCFfLHtAodqEIAqw)

Does anyone know what type of motherboard it is, ITX, Micro ATX etc?

Thank you

Comment: This seems off topic to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at it, it appears to be mini-ITX, but as often as not these types of things are proprietary.  As well, if you're planning to replace it, you'd have to modify the case because it doesn't have a swappable faceplate.  They don't state it in the specs because they don't intend for it to be replaceable (except as a repair part).